# Quadratic equation with one root in $[0,1]$ and other root in $[1,\infty]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Find the values of $a$ for which $x^2-ax+2=0$ has one root in $[0,1]$ and other root in $[1,\infty]$.

The twoo rots are $$\frac{a\pm\sqrt{a^2-8}}{2}$$

The smaller root should be less than $1$.

So $$a-\sqrt{a^2-8}\le 2$$
$$a-2\le\sqrt{a^2-8}$$
$$a^2+4-4a\le a^2-8$$
$$a\ge 3$$

How will I find the upper bound for $a$? And what is the general approach to solve such problems where the roots are constrained between two values?

Comment: $a-\sqrt{a^2-8}\le 2$.

Comment: Shouldn't your first inequality be divided by 2 (so that it is less than 2 and not 1)?!

Comment: Regardless, I think your strategy is correct. I don't see a problem even if you get $a \geq 9/2$... now try plugging in the reverse inequality and the other sign and see what bounds you get.

Comment: Oops. My mistake....

Comment: Caution, $a<b$ doesn't imply $a^2<b^2$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes but in this question a is assumed to be greater than $\sqrt 8$

Comment: @corbah: this is nowhere said explicitly.

Comment: @YvesDaoust the first constraint you should find is $a>\sqrt 8$, otherwise you don't have 2 real roots.

Comment: @corbah: I repeat, this is not said explicitly in the discussion. It is left implicit by the author. This is not good practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First the two roots need to exist, then $$a^2>8.$$

Then the two conditions are

$$a-\sqrt{a^2-8}\le2,\\a+\sqrt{a^2-8}\ge2,$$ or
$$a-2,2-a\le\sqrt{a^2-8}.$$

This is equivalent to

$$(a-2)^2\le a^2-8,\\12\le 4a.$$

This condition is stronger than the first one.

Answer (score 1):

For the upper bound you can use the rule:

> Consider $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ Multiplication of the roots are equal to
>   $\frac{c}{a}$

That is, if $r_1*r_2 = 2$ in this question.

If $0<r_1<1$, then $r_2 = \frac{2}{r1} > 1$